# where is libcommonCrypto.dylib in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to Know where it is because I want to know how functions in libcommonCrypto.c look like. So then I can assign Swift function along to its. in swift code I found this "dlopen("/usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib", RTLD_NOW) " but I can't find after I look up at the path.

Comment: Just do `import CommonCrypto` no?

Comment: I want to see C File Please

Answer (score 0):

On macOS, the path of `libcommonCrypto.dylib` is `/usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib`.

For iOS simulator the path of `libcommonCrypto.dylib` is `${RuntimeRoot}/usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib`.

The `RuntimeRoot` is the root directory for runtime, for example `/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 12.0.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot`